# Apache Redirect regex to move a site to a subsite

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

I've lacked foresight and hosted my site on the main domain of a particular server (http://myserver/). Now that I want two different sites on that server, it's time to move my initial site to a subsite (http://myserver/site1) so I can have site2, site3, etc.

It's easy enough to do:-

```
Redirect / /site1/
```

but then URIs like http://myserver/page1 don't get redirected to http://myserver/site1/page1

I've tried the simple (and obviously wrong):-

```
RedirectMatch ^.*$ /site1/$1
```

but that results in infinite recursion.

Most of the resources for doing that involve mod_rewrite with a few conditionals, but I'm really more comfortable with Redirect, so how can I get the equivalent of the above RedirectMatch line while ignoring any result which begins with site1 (to avoid infinite recursion)?

Comment: I'm.... not sure if you even read the question?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need regex lookahead at the start, and I've found two ways (depending on how many exceptions you need). The simple one is:-

```
RedirectMatch ^(?!/site1)(.*) /site1/$1
```

This does a lookahead from the start of the URI, ignoring any URI which starts with /site1.

If you need to exclude more than just one subsite, try this:-

```
RedirectMatch ^(?!(/site1|/site2))(.*) /site1/$2)
```